# Bulk applying thumbs to video files? - Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10

Example:
[image: Example]

Got this in many of my shows folders. How can I apply the thumbs as the video thumbnails?

Found this: [Tag Editor](https://github.com/Martchus/tageditor)

But doesn't work in bulk.

Thanks!

Comment: Try this in powershell, `Get-ChildItem . -Filter *.mkv |
ForEach-Object {
$file = $_.BaseName
tageditor -s cover=$file-thumb.jpg -f $file.mkv
}`

Comment: Getting this error:

    At line:1 char:70
    + ... Filter *.mkv | ForEach-Object { $file = $_.BaseName tageditor -s cove ...
    +                                                         ~~~~~~~~~
    Unexpected token 'tageditor' in expression or statement.
        + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken

`tageditor --help` works however, so it has installed correctly.

Thanks!

Comment: Try this instead `Get-ChildItem . -Filter *.mkv | ForEach-Object { Write-Host tageditor -s cover=$_BaseName-thumb.jpg -f $_BaseName.mkv }`

Comment: Getting an error from writehost for that.

Comment: Or this `dir *.mkv | %{ tageditor -s cover=$_.BaseName-thumb.jpg -f $_.BaseName.mkv }`

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/r0rdLwb.png

Thanks :D